# What to do with the cluster before joining it to a federation v2?

Tags: kubernetes, federation

I'm using federation v2. I installed a federation control plane and join the host cluster into the federation. 
When I joined the second cluster with below code

```
kubefed2 join federated01 --cluster-context federated01 --host-cluster-context xxxx --add-to-registry --v=2
```

I got

```
I0420 22:05:19.420250   24789 join.go:184] Failed to get joining cluster config: context "federated01" does not exist
F0420 22:05:19.420269   24789 join.go:133] Error: context "federated01" does not exist
```

How to add joining cluster config? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have to provide cluster, context and authentication details to federation control plane in order to join new member:

> Furthermore, federation control plane requires credentials of the
>   joined clusters to operate on them. These credentials are obtained
>   from the local kubeconfig. kubefed join uses the cluster name
>   specified as the argument to look for the cluster’s context in the
>   local kubeconfig. If it fails to find a matching context, it exits
>   with an error.

You might be able to check `kubeconfig` on the cluster you are willing to join with a command:

`kubectl config view`.

Next, you can manually inject sufficient cluster information into the host cluster `kubeconfig`:

`kubectl config set-cluster`

`kubectl config set-context`

`kubectl config set-credentials`

Find more information about multi cluster access in the related official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/).

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that there is no context **federated01** in the config file: *~/.kube/config*. The context requires some other parameters to be added to the config. And when the context will be created properly you'll be able to establish connection to the clusters from the host one and join them to the Federation.

Let's see in details how to inject mentioned info to the config.
The most universal and common applicable way is to establish connection between clusters via API endpoint.

**On the federated01 cluster:**

1. Get the API endpoint of *federated01* cluster, e.g.:
   *https://federated01.example.com/api/*
2. Get api access token for ***federated01*** cluster, e.g.: *eyYNCzwS4F57w*

**On the host cluster:**

3. Create user e.g. *kubefed-user1* and add token to the config file:

***kubectl config set-credentials kubefed-user1 --token='eyYNCzwS4F57w'***

4. Add cluster record to the config and map API endpoint to it:

***kubectl config set-cluster kubefed-federated01 --server='https://federated01.example.com/api/'***

5. Finally, describe the context *federated01* that was missed in your case:

***kubectl config set-context federated01 --cluster=kubefed-federated01 --user=kubefed-user1 --namespace=default***

6. Check whether the *federated01* cluster is accessible or not from the host cluster:

***kubectl --context federated01 get nodes***

If you'll see the cluster nodes it means that you can join the *federated01* cluster to Federation:

***kubefedctl join federated01 --v=2 --host-cluster-context xxxx --kubefed-namespace=yyyy***

The namespace **yyyy** is namespace where the kubefed is installed.
In case the official documentation looks rather complicated you may get more details in this [tutorial](https://jelastic.com/blog/kubernetes-cluster-federation/) based on the latest KubeFed version. Tutorial describes two cluster connection types and some other specifics that can be helpful having a hybrid infrastructure.